# Configure nservicebus to automatically create servicebus queue and error queue on azure

Tags: azure, queue, nservicebus, servicebus

We are currently using nservicebus to read message off an azure servicebus queue.

I can create the queues I need through code but does anyone know if I can setup the config file to create the error and input queues automatically on azure?

Answer (score 1):

All input queues are created automatically by default, but destination queues are never created automatically (to avoid creating rogue queues)

So if some instance is reading the errorqueue it should be created, otherwise you would have to create it manually.

Do note that instances do not start up at the same speed in azure, so it might be that a destination queue does not yet exist when a role tries to send information, while in the mean time the worker is still booting and will create that queue a few seconds later. This will sort itself out over time usually, but for critical parts or production deployments I advise you to create queues manually before publishing the first time.

Makes sense?